# I want to put validation on a search button to check the studentid availability

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

i have developed followin code to check the availabilty of Studentid on the click of search button, but unable to do validation, plz help in this regard
I have following code:

```
$("#stud1search").click(function(e) {
        var id = $('#studentidd').val();

        if(id!="")
            {              
                        jQuery.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: '../jsp/admin/master/Studentinfo.jsp?stdid='+id,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(msg) {
                if($.trim(msg)==1)
                    {
                        $('#searchkaro').html("Student Id: Student Id already exist");
                    }
                    else
                {    
               $("#studentmother").html(msg);
              $("#searchkaro").load("../jsp/admin/master/Studentinfo.jsp");
              //$("#searchkaro").val("");
            }}

});            }
            else
            {
            $('#searchkaro').html("Enter Student Id");
            }

});
```

Comment: it might be `undefined`  or `" "`.

Comment: what validation is failing?

Comment: What can `id` be? Numbers only?

Comment: Is the id mentioned in your code `$('#studentidd')`is attached with your DOM ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you do not want

```
var id = $('#studentidd').val();
```

but

```
var id = $('#studentid').val();
```

Hard to know without seeing your html